# How to convert this string representation of an array into an actual php array

Tags: php

Here is an example:

```
$array = "[[51.228697283276,0.45897198252166],[51.228697283276,0.59374016480853],[51.312903819352,0.59374016480853],[51.312903819352,0.45897198252166]]";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like JSON. You can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to decode it:

```
json_decode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for make this string to an array

```
    <?php 
$string ="[[51.228697283276,0.45897198252166],[51.228697283276,0.59374016480853],[51.312903819352,0.59374016480853],[51.312903819352,0.45897198252166]]";
$array = explode(',',$string);
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $array[$i] = trim($array[$i],'[[');
    $array[$i] = trim($array[$i],']]');
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); ?>
```

Comment: And why would that be better than `json_decode($string)`?